# Centering navbar buttons in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my hands onto some web designing and I was not able to figure out how to make the navigation buttons in my project centered. I would like the buttons from Home to Page 3 centered and was wondering if there was a simple way to do that in the HTML file alone without needing a separate CSS class. 
[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website Name</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost impossible to give an answer without actual code. You should post HTML and CSS related code.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added it now.

Answer (score 1):

Make some changes in Bootstrap.CSS
May be like this...

```
.nav navbar-nav
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Check here => [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/98314)

Comment: Hi, in your preview you have the homepage button centered and the rest left and right. I wanted the homepage button to be on the left with the other buttons centered.

Comment: preview is just sample. I think you can make some changes in bootstrap.css. Find your class .nav navbar-default , and add text-align value. text-align: center;. I think this may work :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can accomplish this is by adjusting some CSS properties. Basically remove the float from navbar-nav and center the text. But if you really want them to be centered, you have to account for the `navbar-brand` class by assigning it a width and adding a negative margin equal to half that width to the `navbar-nav`.

See working Example Snippets.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .container-fluid,
  .navbar.navbar-default .container {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin-left: -75px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website Name</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Mobile Center**

```css
.navbar.navbar-default .container-fluid,
.navbar.navbar-default .container {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin-left: -75px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered,
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container-fluid .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
    margin-left: -75px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#">Website Name</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this css will get your navigation button in center position.

```
navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3wh0gyy/)